# Simulate login action to VBulletin using C#

Tags: c#, post, vbulletin

I trying to write a program (C#) that can login and create new thread into VBulletin forums. I tried 2 way:

1) Use **HttpWebRequest** : Login is done. However creating new thread is fail. This is posting code:

```
public static void CreateNewThread(string url,string fId, string title, string message, string tag)
    {
        url += "newthread.php?do=postthread";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        //string result = "";

        string values = "subject=" + title
                        + "&message=" + message
                        + "&tag=" + tag
                        + "&do=postthread"
                        + "&f=" + fId
                        + "&s="
                        + ""
                        ;

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = values.Length;

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; // prevents 417 error

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write(values);
        }

        HttpWebResponse c = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    }
```

When a execute the code above, no any theard has been created !

2) Use WebBrowser control:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("navbar_username").InnerText = "admin";
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("navbar_password").InnerText = "123";
```

But I cant not submit because the  has no name/id, and Login button is same ! Please tell me how to submit a form without form name/id and button name/id ?

Thanks !

Best regard,

Answer (score 0):

Try simulating post data instead of filling out the form:

```
string postData = "username=Kurresmack&password=pw&action=login&url=/";
webBrowser1.Navigate("www.sweclockers.com/forum/member.php", "", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you reply ! However the code you provide seem not work. It just redirect to member.php only and status is un-login. I tested on VBB 3x and 4x.

Please review it !

Best regard !

Comment: DId you change the values to match yours? I used that exact code (Except username and password) to sign into sweclockers and it worked like a charm

Comment: This is my code:

string postData = "username=Admin&password=123456&action=login&url=/";
webBrowser1.Navigate("localhost/vbb4x/member.php","", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");

Tell me if you see mistakes ! Thanks !

Comment: Please show me the form of your page. You will have to check the values(action = login & url=/). They are hidden fields of the form that you need to "fake"

Comment: Thanks for your support, auto login feature is done ! However, I can not create new thread via post method. Can you help me again ?

Comment: Your should be able to do it the same way. Just check the form that is on the createthread page and take all the values from there. Make sure that you navigate to the action of the form

Comment: I tried it the same way but it failed. Cause the posting coding can not get SecurityToken of the loggin action before. That 's a great anti-spamming featue :)