# Automatically fill username password into windows prompt using asp.net or jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

There's a third party site that many of our users access. I have the username and passwords already stored in our DB. Is it possible to programmatically enter the username and password once this site' URL prompts the user and click the submit button?  Anyway of even doing this on the server side?

Thanks for any insight into this.

Comment: I'm guessing the site doesn't have any functionality you can find to allow you to specify values to pre-fill? And asking them to implement that is out of the question, right?

Comment: That should never be possible, because you should NEVER save the real passwords, only (salted) hashes of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe there is any way to do this with Javascript.  Even in an iFrame I believe the DOMs are separate and the internal cannot be accessed from the parent page. See [<iframe> javascript access parent DOM across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)

I would look at the form and pull the action and form fields out.  Then in a server side action you can post directly to the action with the data from the database and redirect the client to the return value. This post may help for a C# solution [Simulate login action to VBulletin using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453844/simulate-login-action-to-vbulletin-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you open the third party site in a frame or separate window, your site will not have Javascript access to do anything to that page because it is Cross Domain.

Here are just some thoughts:

1. Search the third party site or contact someone from the site to see if they have any API for their site.  They may already have support for what you want to do implemented in an API.
2. Use a tool like Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to see what information their login page is sending to their server.  Create a form on your site that mimic's their login page and submits the login info to their website.

The second option isn't very reliable because if they change their site at all, your code breaks.  With an API, the site at least considers those using the API before they make changes that might break something.  Also, I am not sure how secure this is.  If you end up passing the password through the page, there is a chance someone could intercept/view it.

For the most part, I don't think this is possible without the help of the third part site.  I hope these thoughts give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Would loading the other site into an iframe work? From there you might be able to call some JavaScript to set the form input values and hit submit. Then, once the user has a valid login / session cookie, ignore the iframe and just redirect them to the third party site altogether.

Completely untested theory, and something tells me it won't work, but it's an idea.

Comment: Same Origin policy will not allow that.